# Evaluating expression tree - C++

Tags: c++, tree

I'm having some trouble with this evaluation function with no pointer as a parameter.

Here's the class definition:

```
class ExpressionTree
    {
    private:
        double data;            // Used for leaf nodes only.
        char operation;         // Used for non-leaf nodes only.
        ExpressionTree *left;   // Will be NULL for a leaf.
        ExpressionTree *right;  // Will be NULL for a leaf.
    };
```

As you can see, there are only pointers for the `left` and `right` subtrees of the expression tree.

Here's my attempt at an `evaluate()` function (note no pointer being passed as a parameter)

```
double ExpressionTree::evaluate() const {
    if(left != NULL && right != NULL) {
        double val;

        double left_val = left->data;
        double right_val = right->data;

        if(operation == '+') val = left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
        else if(operation == '*') val = left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
        else val = this->data;
        return val;
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

When running it against this code, I get a Segmentation Fault:

```
ExpressionTree buildComplex() {
    double x, y, z;
    cout << "enter three double values, x, then y, then z\n";
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    ExpressionTree ex(x), ey(y), ez(z), e2(2),
        yz = ey * ez,
        y2 = e2 * ey,
        sum1 = ex + yz,
        full = sum1 + y2;
    return full;
}

void test4() {
    cout << "test4: construct and evaluate more complex\n";
    ExpressionTree e = buildComplex();
    cout << "x + y * z + 2 * y = " << e.evaluate() << endl;
}
```

I believe the segmentation fault is from the recursive call in the `evaluate()` function.

The question I am asking is: How can I recursively evaluate the tree without a node being passed as a parameter to the function? I could understand if there was only one layer below the root node, but there will be multiple layers and I don't understand how to solve all of the other layers.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Tree with no root node' is a contradiction in terms. Of course there is a root node: otherwise there is no tree. But it doesn't have to be *in the tree*. Your variable `e` **is** a pointer to the root node, and so is the value of `this` inside the first call to `evaluate()`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I rephrased the question a bit to add clarity. I cannot edit the first and third snippets of code, only the second. When I try to use e in my `evaluate()` function I get undeclared identifier errors.

Comment: Your root pointer is `this`. Do you understand how objects work in C++? (`this` roughly means "the current object")

Comment: Also, I suspect your crash has nothing to do with `this` or `e`, and everything to do with trying to use objects after they're destroyed. But there's no way to know that with only the posted code.

Comment: Nobody said anything about using `e` in `evaluate()`. You can't. It's out of scope. Please read what I wrote.

Comment: I've rephrased / changed the question to be more specific. I now understand using `this` as a means of pointing to the root node. Now I'm asking about how to solve the problem using recursion given no node in the parameter of the `evaluate()` function.

Comment: You don't *need* a node parameter in `evaluate()`. You have `this`. It is the current node. The first time, it's the root, Next time, it's the root's left or right child. And so on.

Comment: Where are the constructors and `+` and `*` operators defined for this class?

Comment: I can't help but notice that ExpressionTree has no constructor. That means  your `left` and `right` pointers will be uninitialized, which appears to be the cause of your segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `evaluate` on the same node, creating an infinite loop.

If you want to call it on the sub-expressions, use `left->evaluate()`.

---

There are likely more problems, one I've noticed is this one:

```
else if(right != NULL)
```

This makes no sense, just because `left` wasn't `NULL` you're going to ignore the right subexpression?

Comment: I rewrote the `evaluate()` function, and there are no longer any errors, however when I use `x=2, y=3, and z=4`, it answers out 14, instead of the correct answer of 20.

Comment: Disregard that last comment. I realized I put a plus instead of a multiplication sign on the multiplication case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `evaluate()` method is nonsense. It should look something like this:

```
double ExpressionTree::evaluate() const
{
    if (left != NULL && right != NULL)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
        case '+':
            return left->evaluate()+right->evaluate();
        case '-':
            // remaining operators left as an exercise for the reader
        // ....
        }
    }
    // I'm assuming there are only binary operators,
    // but if you have unary operators, i.e. unary '-', it's a simple
    // extension of what's here
    return data;
}
```